# Dynamic table formatting is not working

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to create dynamic table with limited columns (depends on requirements).
So I have 2 pages.

**results.php**

This page have some list of results with add to compare check box like in image:

[image]

when user click on add to compare check box a small div pop up with compare button like shown in image:

[image: after click add to compare checkbox this happens]

Now when user click on compare button it will take user on next page and shows compare results in table like shown in image:

[image: compare results]

My problem is, I want compare result like this:

[image: how can i display my headers along with row]

My code for table is:

```
 <?php
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT c.course_title,c.course_description,c.course_fee,c.course_duration,i.instructor_name,u.university_name,m.course_provider_name from course_info_table c inner join instructor_ref_table i on c.course_instructor_id = i.instructor_id inner join university_ref_table u on c.university_id = u.university_id inner join course_provider_table m on c.course_provider_id = m.course_provider_id and (course_id = '$course_1' or '$course_2')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
?>
<table>

        <tr>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Fee</th>
            <th>duration</th>
            <th>university</th>
            <th>instructor</th>
            <th>Mooc Provider</th>
        </tr>


        <?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    ?>

            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['course_title'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['course_description'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['course_fee'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['course_duration'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['university_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['instructor_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['course_provider_name'];?></td>
            </tr>

    </table>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: while should be out side of the table <div class="row col-md-12"> while(){     <div class="col-md-6"> ...table </div> }  </div>

Comment: @parvez Try my answer and let me know :-) thanks.

Comment: why is there so much whitespace on this question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following it should be **work**:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT c.course_title,c.course_description,c.course_fee,c.course_duration,i.instructor_name,u.university_name,m.course_provider_name from course_info_table c inner join instructor_ref_table i on c.course_instructor_id = i.instructor_id inner join university_ref_table u on c.university_id = u.university_id inner join course_provider_table m on c.course_provider_id = m.course_provider_id and (course_id = '$course_1' or '$course_2')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));


$compare_rows = array();

$compare_count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if($compare_count == 0){
        $compare_rows[0] = '<th>Course Title</th>';
        $compare_rows[1] = '<th>Description</th>';
        $compare_rows[2] = '<th>Fee</th>';
        $compare_rows[3] = '<th>duration</th>';
        $compare_rows[4] = '<th>university</th>';
        $compare_rows[5] = '<th>instructor</th>';
        $compare_rows[6] = '<th>Mooc Provider</th>';
    }
    $compare_rows[0] .= "<td>".$row['course_title']."</td>";
    $compare_rows[1] .= "<td>".$row['course_description']."</td>";
    $compare_rows[2] .= "<td>".$row['course_fee']."</td>";
    $compare_rows[3] .= "<td>".$row['course_duration']."</td>";
    $compare_rows[4] .= "<td>".$row['university_name']."</td>";
    $compare_rows[5] .= "<td>".$row['instructor_name']."</td>";
    $compare_rows[6] .= "<td>".$row['course_provider_name']."</td>";
    $compare_count++;
}

if(!empty($compare_rows)){
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($compare_rows as $compare_row){
        echo "<tr>".$compare_row."</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

jQuery: for add/remove comparison of [jsfiddle.net/47jev3f4](http://jsfiddle.net/47jev3f4)

```
$(".compare").change(function() {
    var check = $(this).val();      
    if(this.checked) {  
        $('#compare_box').show();       
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'compare.php',
            dataType : "JSON",
            data:{value : check},
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);   
                console.log(data.id);
                var output = "<div class='col-md-3 photo-grid js-compare-check js-compare-"+check+"' style='float:left'>";
                output += "<div id='course_title' class='well well-sm'>";
                output += "<h4>"+data.title+"</h4>";
                output+="<textarea class='hidden' id='hidden_title' name='course_title[]' value=>"+data.title+"</textarea>";
                output+="</div>";
                output+="<input type='hidden' id='hidden_id' name='course_id[]' value="+data.id+">";
                output+="</div>";
                $('#result').append(output); 
            }
        });
    }else{
        $(".js-compare-"+check).remove(); 

        if($(".js-compare-check").length == 0){
            $('#compare_box').hide();       
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: @RkBala its working,thanks,can you help me in writing script if user again click on add to compare checkbox,it should remove that particular course from selection

Comment: @parvez Welcome :-) You try something, then i will help you. Because I dont know your front-end

Comment: @RkBala [link]https://jsfiddle.net/47jev3f4/ here is my front end ,how to remove seleted result from comare box after unchecking the button

Comment: Please use the js code in my answer and let me know. Thanks :-)

Comment: with which element i should use .js-compare class ,its not working @bala

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117784/discussion-between-maths-rkbala-and-parvez).

Comment: thanks for this,please help me with new problem [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476243/create-compare-box-on-checkbox-click-not-working