# create compare box on checkbox click not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on add to compare feature of a website,so on current page there are some results which have a checkbox named add to compare attached.

So when user click on add to compare checkbox the selected result get appended to one `compare box div` and this process go on.

my problem is,when user want to uncheck or remove the selected result from `compare div box` he should be able to remove it.

Here's is my code which i have done till yet
**html**

```
    <div id='compare_box'>
    <form action="compare_results.php" method="POST">
      <div id='result'>

      </div>
      <button id="compare_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">compare</button>
      </form>
        </div>

     <div class="col-md-3 photo-grid " style="float:left"> 

        <div class="well well-sm">

        <h4><small><?php echo $title; ?></small></h4>

     <br>
     <div class="features">
          <div id="compare_feature">
     <input type ='checkbox' name="compare" class="compare" value="<?php echo $id;?>">add to compare
          </div>

    <button  class='btn btn-sm btn-info favourite_feature'  value="<?php echo $id;?>">add to favourite</button>

     </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
 #compare_box
{
  display: none;
}
```

**ajax call**

```
        $(".compare").change(function() {
if(this.checked) {  
  $('#compare_box').show();
var check = $(this).val();      
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'compare.php',
        dataType : "JSON",
        data:{value : check},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);   
        console.log(data.id);
       var output = "<div class='col-md-3 photo-grid' style='float:left'>";
       output += "<div id='course_title' class='well well-sm'>";
       output += "<h4>"+data.title+"</h4>";
       output+="<textarea class='hidden' id='hidden_title' name='course_title[]' value=>"+data.title+"</textarea>";
        output+="</div>";
        output+="<input type='hidden' id='hidden_id' name='course_id[]' value="+data.id+">";
       output+="</div>";
            $('#result').append(output); 
        }
    });
  }

 });
```

PS:  [I'm trying to implement something like this](http://studyabroad.shiksha.com/usa/mba-colleges-dc)

Answer (score 0):

What is '#compare_box' ? Is it the element that appears when the checkbox disappear (in your exemple at 'your selection')?

Then bind an action on '#result' - precise something that can link your element to check box like an id (when you prepare your html in ajax response).

```
$('#result').on('click', function() {
   $($(this).data('id')).prop('checked', false); // uncheck it
   $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Do the same for when you uncheck a checkbox (find the element with data-id of your check box and remove it)

EDIT : it's not the perfect code to make it work, you might adapt depending on where you bind click or place the data-id

Comment: Okay, it doesn't impact what i said before : under `if (this.checked)` add `var id = this.attr('id');` then add on your div you create `data-id='+id+'` , plus add a tag <a> or <button> to this div to perform click